# submenu hidden under other div

Tags: html, css, submenu

my submenu is getting hidden under the other div. i have used z-index but its not working. following is my menu code. i also tried to change position style alternatively but still no result.

HTML CODE of MENU

```
<div id="menu" class="col-xs-10  col-sm-10 col-md-10">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Our Partnership</li>                    
        <li>About Us</li>
        <li class="hasSub">Our School
            <ul class="submenu">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <li>a</li>
                        <li>b</li>
                        <li>c</li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <li>a</li>
                        <li>b</li>
                        <li>c</li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <li>a</li>
                        <li>b</li>
                        <li>c</li>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Vision & Values</li>
        <li>News</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
#menu{
    float: right;
    color: #2d385b;
    position: relative;
}
#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#menu ul li {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    z-index: 5000;
}
#menu li ul{
    display: none;
    background:#ffffff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position:absolute;
    min-width:450px;
    z-index:999999;
    right: 0px;
}
#menu li ul div {
    float:left;
    z-index:999999;
    border-right: #000 1px solid;
}
#menu li ul div li{
    width: 100%;
}
#menu li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Notice, `col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4` is equal to `col-xs-4`.

Comment: I think `<ul>` should not contain other elements than `<li>`.

Comment: ul will open on li hover. currently ul is opening but its showing under another div